# Isn't the ethereum wallet keystore encrypted?

Tags: mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, password

I created a ethereum wallet ages ago. However, I noticed when I open the ethereum wallet it does not prompt for a passphrase like alethone. Does this mean my keystore is not encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to enter your passphrase when you want to transfer some ethers from your accounts / addresses.

Your encrypted keys will be stored in the following directories with one individual file for each account:

- Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum/keystore
- Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
- Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore